# Why is my panel scrolling up on mobile devices? jQueryMobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I've got a little task viewer with a panel where you can create a task, anyway, the problem I'm having is that when you're on a mobile device and you scroll down the panel, it gets back to the top, so you need to scroll down again to be able to click on the input you want, when you finish filling out(or not) the input and try clicking on the back button to dismiss the keyboard it goes back to the top again.

I tried to use `.focus` but it ignores it.

Why is it happening? How can I fix it? Any help is sincerely appreciated.

**Click on the plus button to open the panel**

**P.S.: I cleared up the code to focus on the issue**

**My Code:**

```css
#header {
  background-color: #72a9dc;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  color: white;
}
.code {
  background-color: #b4d0ec;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.label {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.date {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
  color: black;
}
.detail {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #72a9dc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header" data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <a onclick="onTop();" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>
    <a onclick="newTask();" id="newTask" href="#add-form" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
  </div>

  <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">

    <form class="ui-filterable" id="search">
      <input id="rich-autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search. . .">
    </form>

    <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-input="#rich-autocomplete-input">
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" id="add-form">
    <form class="userform">
      <h2 id="myTitle"></h2>
      <label>Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" min="1" value="" data-clear-btn="false" data-mini="true">
      <label>Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="label" maxlength="20" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
      <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
      <label>Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" min="1" value="" data-clear-btn="false" data-mini="true">
      <label>Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="label" maxlength="20" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
      <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

      <label>Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" min="1" value="" data-clear-btn="false" data-mini="true">
      <label>Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="label" maxlength="20" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
      <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

      <label>Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" min="1" value="" data-clear-btn="false" data-mini="true">
      <label>Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="label" maxlength="20" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
      <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

      <label>Code:</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" min="1" value="" data-clear-btn="false" data-mini="true">
      <label>Label:</label>
      <input type="text" id="label" maxlength="20" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
      <label>Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

      <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini" onclick="addTask();">Save</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `href="#"` which can cause the page to actually go to the top because the # is a valid link, you can (and should) use `href="javascript:void(null);"` which is just an empty javascript function that will make sure your button will do nothing else than what it should do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, I'm gonna try it then I'll return :) +1

Comment: Oh damn it, yes it worked, I forgot to mark it, I'm sorry, thanks for reminding me. I fixed it using a different method, but your answer worked too

Comment: Awesome, no problem :)